# He comes to feet, spins in behind

Tags: meaning

What does the sentence "**He comes to feet, spins in behind**" mean in football/soccer term?

Full sentence:

> He comes to feet, spins in behind and just makes it difficult for defenders and easy for midfielders to pick passes.
>   — https://www.arsenal.com/news/wilshere-im-feeling-better-each-game

Comment: It should be "He comes _to_ his feet". It means "He stands up"

Comment: @Mitch see the link to the soccer article I've edited into OP's text. And it certainly does not mean *stands up*

Comment: @k1eran oh wow I've never heard that wording before

Answer (score 3):

*He comes to feet* means that, due to good positioning play, *he* (i.e. the attacker, Alexis) manages to move himself into relative positions where the midfielders (e.g. Wilshere) can kick the ball cleanly and directly to him on the ground.

*Spins in behind* means after he gets the ball he quickly gets goal-side of the defender.

I think it's clearer in this [quote](https://talksport.com/football/exclusive-theo-walcott-deserves-run-arsenals-main-striker-talksport-told-150929168474), coincidentally also about Arsenal:

> “Walcott is 26 and if Wenger’s going to stick to what he’s been saying, he has to give Walcott a run as that centre-forward.
>
> “I think he offers a bit more than Giroud going in behind defences, he stretches defences and defenders hate running back towards their own goal.
>
> “From a midfielder’s point of view, **if you’ve got a willing runner to get in behind and threaten defenders, it gives them a different option rather than Giroud who comes to feet all the time**.”

Comment: Your first paragraph was a bit confusing, so I’ve slightly rephrased it—feel free to improve or roll back if I’ve misunderstood what you were trying to say (I’ve never heard the expressions either and know bugger-all about football).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Cheers!